# Find next larger number with same number of prime factors

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-factorization

Is there are way to determine, given a (composite) number $n$ and a list of its prime factors, the next larger (composite) number with the same number of prime factors? *Clarification: **Not** the same number of different factors, but the **number of factors overall, including multiplicies.***

So for example given $n = 12$ (with the 3 prime factors $2, 2, 3$) I want to find the number $18$ (with the 3 prime factors $2, 3, 3$). And after that, I'd like to get $20$ (with the 3 prime factors $2, 2, 5$).

Put differently I'd like a good way to represent / calculate the monotonically increasing series of numbers with the same number of prime factors.

Assumption: I know the series of prime numbers.

Comment: Seems unlikely to have a good answer (consider the case when $n$ is prime, for instance).

Comment: Oh, should've said that: composite numbers only

Comment: Knowing prime numbers I guess you could use $log_pq$ to determine the order of these composite numbers. Say f.e. if is bigger $p^2q$ or $pt$. Perhaps using then something like knapsack. The structure I imagine is polynomials over $p_i$ with $k$ $1$s and the others $0$s

Comment: Even with composites you might have one prime factor only.  For example you have $3^4,11^2,5^3,2^7$ as consecutive (non-trivial) prime powers.  What sort of simple rule will yield that?

Comment: I guess you want the same _prime signature_. Should it be the number of different prime factors, you'd have 14 after 12, since both have two. Or... wait, did you mean the _total number of prime factors with multiplicities_? If that is the case, then sorry for my edit and feel free to revert it, or better edit the title again to that effect.

Comment: In any case, **lulu** is right: an answer that is faster than brute force is unlikely.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, I mean with multiplicities. I tried to clarify a bit. I fear that an answer faster than brute force is unlikely, too, but was hoping that knowing the prime numbers would help... (using it as an "oracle")